# How to get column info from oracle table you don't own (without using describe)?

Tags: oracle

How would one get columns information on table which he doesn't own, but has select granted? This is, without using `DESCRIBE table_name`. Consider this example:

```
// user bob owns table STUDENTS
grant select on students to josh;
// now josh logs in, normally he would do
describe bob.students;
// but he's looking for something along the lines
select column_name from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'STUDENTS';
// which doesn't work, as josh doesn't own any tables on his own
```

Any ideas? Is this even doable?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
select column_name from all_tab_columns where table_name = 'STUDENTS';
```

**edit:** or, even better

```
select owner, column_name from all_tab_columns where table_name = 'STUDENTS';
```

Answer (score 4):

Have a look on [oracle data dictionary](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96524/c05dicti.htm), it should help.

Answer (score 1):

```
CONN HR/HR@HSD;

GRANT SELECT ON EMPLOYEES TO SCOTT;

CONN SCOTT/TIGER@HSD;

SELECT owner, column_name FROM all_tab_columns WHERE table_name = 'EMPLOYEES';
```